Linear elliptic operator in linear parabolic equations
Let $X \hookrightarrow H$ be two Hilbert spaces with continuous embedding. Suppose that $X$  is dense in $H$. Upon identification of $H$ with its dual space $H^{*}$, the Gelfand triple of Hilbert spaces is obtained: $X \hookrightarrow H \cong H^{*} \hookrightarrow X^{*}$. For $T>0$ and given data
$$
u_{0} \in H, \quad f \in L^{2}\left((0,T); X^{*}\right),
$$
Consider the parabolic problem
$$
\begin{aligned}
u^{\prime}(t)+A u(t) & = f(t), \quad t \in(0, T), \\
u(0) & =u_{0}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here, $A: X \rightarrow X^{*}$ is a linear elliptic operator (in space) defined by
$$
\langle A u, v\rangle_{X^{*} \times X}=a(u, v), \quad \forall u, v \in X,
$$
for a bilinear form $a: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is assumed to be continuous and coercive. More precisely, there are two constants  $\alpha, \beta>0$ such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
|a(u, v)| & \leq \alpha\|u\|_{X}\|v\|_{X}, \quad \forall u, v \in X, \\
a(u, u) & \geq \beta\|u\|_{X}^{2},\quad \forall u \in X .
\end{aligned}
$$
A space-time function $u$ satisfies
\begin{equation*}
  u(t) = \sum_{j=0}^{n} a_{j} P_{j}(t), \quad a_{j} \in X,~~ n\in \mathbb{N},
\end{equation*}
where $P_j(t)$ is the orthogonal polynomial of degree $j$ on $[0,T]$.
For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there holds
\begin{equation*}
  Au=\sum_{j=0}^{n}Aa_{j} P_{j}(t), 
\end{equation*}
My question is: if $u(t) \in L^2((0,T); X)$, meaning $n = +\infty$, does the result still hold? Why?
Thanks for any help.
